# Binding Property FixedAssetId not found on ViewModel what did I do wrong here?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

Hi does anybody know what did I do wrong here? I wanted to display the FixedId property to my UI but I got an error saying Property not found on ViewModel I'm fetching data from web API and already got the data from API all I wanna do is to display the Id to the UI I'm working on Xamarin Forms here's my code thank you for your help guys.

**My XAML and ViewModel**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:App3.ViewModel" 
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainPageViewModel"
             x:Class="App3.MainPage">    
    
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                  IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                  RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshData}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="4">
                            <Label Text="{Binding FixedAssetId}"
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   FontSize="Medium"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

**My ViewModel**

```
    public async Task<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {           
                var token = await GetAccessToken();
            List<Employee> EmployeeList = null;
            JObject JSonObject = null;               

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var uri = "https://my-project.azurewebsites.net";
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                        var result = await client.GetAsync("/fa/ID000001234");
                                                IsRefreshing = false;

                        if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            throw new Exception("Error GetEmployees method" + result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);                   
                    
                        EmployeeList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);                      

                }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                         throw new Exception("Error GetEmployees method");
                    }
                                Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(EmployeeList);
            }
            return EmployeeList[0];
        }
    ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees;
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
        {
            get
            {
                return _employees;
            }
            set
            {
                _employees = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        bool _isRefreshing;
        public bool IsRefreshing
        {
            get 
            {
                return _isRefreshing;
            }
            set 
            {
                _isRefreshing = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public Command RefreshData
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(() =>
                {
                    GetEmployees();
                });
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I search the property named FixedAssetId in your viewmodel, but I can't find  it. So you should create an appropriate property.

Comment: Show us what `Employee` looks like. Does it have a  `FixedAssetId` on it?

Comment: Yeah you both right, I missed some property in Employee model thank you so much for your help :)